# C STL аналог

Tags: c

Нужна библиотека на С (чистый С, не С/С++), подобная STL, для работы с очередями, деревьями, списками и т.п. Будет использоваться в драйвере. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [glib](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib). Есть очереди, списки, деревья и многое другое.
В [английской википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib) так и сказано: "во многих задачах glib представляет собой аналог STL в C++".

Comment: А не странно использовать GLib в драйвере? Он же слишком тяжёлый

Comment: Быть беде. В режиме ядра стандартные функции будут недоступны, так что возможности из glib надо использовать крайне осторожно. Видимо, придётся просто выдрать реализацию коллекций из glib.

Comment: glib наверняка использует malloc для динамического выделения памяти.. а в ядре malloc недоступен. Так что я понятия не имею, как эту штука может работать в драйвере... разве что драйвер работает не как модуль ядра.